# Setinterval for a function

Tags: angularjs, setinterval

Would you be so kind and help me modify the function below and set 'setInterval' that the function is executed every 5sec?

Thanks in advance!

```
$scope.updateIndividual = function () {
        console.log('Updating individual', $scope.user.individual);

        $scope.user.individual.professionalExperience = experiences;
        $scope.user.individual.trainings = trainings;
        $scope.user.individual.education = education;
        $http({
            url: '/individual/update-individual',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                individual: $scope.user.individual
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
                $scope.userConfirm = "Changes Saved Successfully";
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.userConfirm = "";
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                $scope.userConfirm = "Something went wrong, please try again";
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: you want to run `$scope.updateIndividual` function every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2):

Inject `$interval` into the controller and use it to run the function every 5 seconds, like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.updateIndividual = function() {...};
    $interval($scope.updateIndividual, 5000);
});
```